# What am I doing wrong with 2's complement?

Tags: twos-complement

Trying to understand why `~8` is `-9`.

My incorrect math is as follows:

1.) `8` in binary is `1000`.
2.) Invert all bits: `0111`.
3.) Add 1: `1000`.

....and now I've got the same thing I started with. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In other words: `1000` is `-8` in two's complement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four bits can only represent -8 .. 7 in two's complement. To do your math on 8 you'll need at least five bits.

What you've done here is basically an overflow, as your `8` value is originally encoded as `-9` anyway.

Here's a reworked version:

```
 8 = 01000
~8 = 10111
+1 = 11000
```

The secondary component of that is `1000`, which when inverted is `0111`, which is 7, and 7+1, accounting for the offset, puts you back at 8.

Comment: Oh....so it should be `01000`, which becomes `10111` and then `11000`....but how is that -9 either? seems like 8 to me if the first bit indicates negative.

Comment: Time to visit the [Wikipedia crash course page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). If the first bit is set that means "negative" and then the meaning of all subsequent bits is inverted.

Comment: Ah I think I get it. But you mean the meaning of all subsequent bits is inverted *and then you subtract 1*, right? That's the only thing that would make sense of the chart of "Three-bit two's-complement integers" on the top right of the wiki page.

Comment: Think about what you did to compute the two's complement in the first place: You inverted the bits and added one. To interpret inverted numbers, you need to de-invert them, which due to the nature of binary means inverting them again. Adding 1 to an inverted binary number is the same as subtracting 1 from a non-inverted one, so you need to add 1 back on to undo that subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work in 8 bits.

```
8 = 00001000
9 = 00001001

~8 = 11110111 Inverse of 8
```

Now let's do the 2's complement of `9` to get `-9`

```
00001001 9
11110110 Inverse
11110111 Add 1
-9 = 11110111
```

Note that `~8 = -9`